# Code does not recognize already defined variable

Tags: python

beginner here trying to learn, I'm trying to make a code here with the following conditions:

1) If score == "break", then the loop stops
2) else it will keep running with the following conditions in the below code

Problem is when i run the code, the 2nd last line produces an error which says "score is not defined" although i defined it earlier (in bold)

Can anyone advise please.

```
halfmods = []
level100mods = []
fullmods = []


def enter_score():
    score = input("Enter your score here: ")
    level = input("Enter the subject level: ")
    if int(level) == 100:
        typeofmod = input("Is the module full or half? ")
        if typeofmod == "full":
            level100mods.append(score)
        else:
            halfmods.append(score)
    else:
        fullmods.append(score)

while True:
    enter_score()
    if score == "break":
        break
```